# A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, csrf, salt, antiforgerytoken

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Posts", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "publish" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken("Posts/Create")
    <input type="text" id="url" name="url" />
    <input type="submit" value="@Html.Resource("Publish")" />
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult Create(string url)
{
    // stuff that's never reached
}
```

I can't realize what's making this simple form fail on validating the CSRF token.
How can I debug this?

**Update**

If I remove the Salt, it works; the strange thing is it used to work with the Salt, and I can't figure out why it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a salt you have to pass it to the  `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` filter too:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = "Posts/Create")]
public JsonResult Create(string url)
{ 
  ...
```

Comment: I wonder why it wasn't throwing before. Thank you, that was it.